# Do I need a CursorAdapter for each table?

Tags: android, database, listview

I have a database with a content provider. The db has 6 tables. I want to make lists of all the tables. I use loaders and now I have a `CursorAdapter` for a table that works well. I didn't find a way to pass a variable to identify other tables. Do I need a `CursorAdapter` for each table?
This is my CursorAdapter class code:

```
public class extends ActivitiesAdapter CursorAdapter {
    public ActivitiesAdapter (Context context) {
    super (context, null, 0);
}

@Override
public void BindView (View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView categ_list = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.categ_list_text);
    categ_list.setText (cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex (lajesContract.CategoriasEntry.CAT_CGT)));
}

@Override
View public Newview (Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ());
    inflater.inflate return (R.layout.item_layout, null, false);
}
  }
```

As you can see, the `BindView` fills the list with data from the table **lajesContract.CategoriasEntry.CAT_CGT**

How can I pass other tables?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should create a separate adapter for each table.

You could probably factor out the commonalties, but that's pretty much what CursorAdapter does. Further attempts to reuse the adapter will like just create overly complex, brittle code,  with no real benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So clear. I will continue working.